# error attaching to process when run jmap -heap pid

Tags: jvm, jmap

I deployed a microservice with docker container and want to check the jvm information. So I enter the container and find the pid. Then I run jmap -heap pid command, but I get the following error log:

[image: error log capture]

How to fix it?

Comment: @apangin ok, then the other point still holds, questioners should not compile error messages as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux `jmap -heap` works on top of Serviceability Agent which in turn relies on [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) syscall.

By default `ptrace` requires root privileges (or more precisely, `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability). Furthermore, docker default security profile denies `ptrace` syscall either by seccomp or apparmor.

So, in order to allow `ptrace` and `jmap -heap` in a container, it might be needed to add the following docker options:

```
--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined --security-opt=apparmor:unconfined
```

Note: this is not the best solution from security perspective. Consult docker manual to find how to enable particular syscall without switching off [seccomp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) and [apparmor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/).

Even better option would be to avoid `jmap -heap` at all. There are other efficient ways to monitor JVM without Serviceability Agent support, e.g. [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html), [`jstat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) and `JMX`.